# Form field changes causes child component re-render. How to control that?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react functional component and native form. For fields control I read about useState. And as expected that will re-render the form on input filed change. But the problem is am having 2-3 child components. If I use useState they will cause form component and then child component re-render on each input change. How to handle this?

Comment: What is there to handle? If this is not intended behaviour, then your layout is structured wrong (i.e. they should not be child components).

Comment: you usually won't get any good answers if you do not show what you have done. I can roughly point you to `React.memo`, perhaps that will answer your question.

Comment: @nbokmans You right but was just wondering is it any way to ignore unnecessary child rendering